# Store last folder name in path to a variable in PHP

Tags: php, include

I have a php script call "functions.php" that is executed both by itself and by other scripts placed in other folders. I therefore encounter a problem with the code where it tries to include the database file. At first I came up with a quick lazy work around. I amde the script ask twice for the same file like this:

```
include('../database_file.php');
include('../../database_file.php');
```

However, this is not a good solution. It makes a warning every time, since it can't load one of the files. I have therefore decided to make a Switch Statement that reads if the functions.php file was called by itself or from somewhere else and then include the file from the correct path. (If there is a better workaround, please tell.)

I use the following code to read the current path, so I can make an IF Statement that decides wherefrom my database file should be loaded.

```
realpath(dirname(__FILE__));
```

This return a path similar to this:

/var/www/website/public

How can I store only the last folder in the path to a variable / Remove everything before the last /?

Comment: How about `include_once`?

Comment: Are you saying that you wrote include(path to function.inc) inside of the function itself?  Shouldn't you just be able to include it in the first .php file that you would expect to call the function and then if  you need to call it inside of itself you can just use the function call and it will use it yet again.  I do assume that the content of "functions.php" has script that is written as function functionname(), right?  If you are just including a plain old block of code over and over and "calling it a function" you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using `absolute path`? In this way you will not care what is the actual folder, file will be loaded anyway. For example

```
include('/var/www/website/public/path_to_file.php');
```

**Edit**

Since you stated you cannot use `absolute path` then you can use `explode` function on the path's variables so it become an array, now it's easy to get last entry of array wich is your last folder, and store it in a variable

```
$path = realpath(dirname(__FILE__));
$folder_array = explode('/', $path);
$i = count($folder_array) - 1;
$folder = $folder_array[$i];
echo 'Folder is: ' . $folder;
```

this will output

```
Folder is: public
```

Comment: I can't do this, because the code need to be more flexible. I'm building a hosted/web based solution where my customers get a subdomain which is stored in a seperate folder. The code therefore needs to read where it is stored, since it will differ from sub domain to sub domain.